# Ask for a bourne shell grammar

Tags: sh

I came across following bourne shell script snanshot:

```
hosts=( $(cat $TOP/rhost))
j=0
for k in {1..20}
do
  host=${hosts[$j]}
  su  user$k -c  "/usr/bin/rsh $host $TOP/test.sh $JOBNUM $QUEUE $TIME $TOP $LSF_ENVDIR" &
  j=`expr $j + 1`
  j=$(($j%${#hosts[@]}))
done
```

Generally I understand that this script iterate many times to execute test.sh on each host in hosts.
But I didn't know what this line does:

```
  j=$(($j%${#hosts[@]}))
```

It seems that j mod something, which is computed from #hosts[@], what does "#" and "@" mean here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${#hosts[@]}` means the number of items in the array variable "hosts". It's specific to bash as the Bourne shell doesn't have array variables.